# Are there any Craft specific migration tools that extend Yii's built-in functionality?

Tags: migration, deployment

We're working on developing a proper deployment system for projects built on Craft, and wondering if there are any Craft specific tools built-in that can assist with generating database migrations, other than [those included with Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration) itself?

I have more questions, but we'll start here.

Comment: Yeah, covering quite a few topics worth their own answers. Split 'em up and I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Brad Thanks Brad. I'll start here, and see where this leads us. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft has it's own version of Yii's console app, [yiic](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console), in `craft/app/etc/console/yiic.php` and we have a `migrate` command that lets you create, view history, see new migrations, etc. for plugins as well as Craft itself.

We've extended the default `migrate` command to add Craft-specific features and remove some default Yii functionality that we don't want to support (i.e. down migrations).

You can see the available commands to run here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/migrations

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I don't know how I missed this in the docs. I'll investigate this a bit, and ask more as needed. But real quick, the docs are geared toward plugin development (which is great) — is there similar documentation for migrating the main craft DB?